# How to implement Popup menu inside the navigation drawer in android app

Tags: java, android, mobile

I have already created navigation drawer with menu inside. While clicking on the item I do wanna open some kind of POPUP menu, that covers the text of menu, but icons of that navigation drawer are still visible.

On the picture below you can see the way it should work.

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SdgAi.png)

Comment: Have you tried using PopupMenu or are you just asking for someone to do it for you?

Comment: I ve tried. It does not work, because when it pops -> navigation drawer closes. Apart from that, pop up menu would not cover text of menu. Look on screens.